# What is the common use case to create a branch in GitHub instead of locally?

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub. And I read the following description on creating branch in GitHub repository: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/

It seems to me that what they said make sense: "**We recommend creating branches locally, on your computer... Online branch management is useful for simple cases...**"

If all you need is to push to 'master' branch and you have the access right, then you do not need to create another branch on the Git server side(which is the Hub), right?

The reason I can think of to create new branch on Hub is:

1. you do not have permission to push to 'master' directly, so you have to create your own branch on Hub, and push to that branch first(which later can be picked up by 'master' branch), or
2. you need to do code review, and to do that, you need 'pull request', which need a new branch to compare with the master branch.

Am I understanding correctly?

Btw, when I create a new branch on GitHub, is it created right out of the origin/master HEAD?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a number of use cases. Generally they'll all deal with how you organize your workflow. Your example 1 & 2 belong to a same kind of workflow imo: not ready/allowed to merge into master.

The most useful reason I can think of however is **teamwork.** 
Lets say I and one or more other person(s) are working on a feature. We might create a featurebranch and commit our code on it, then push it to GitHub. Regularly check for upstream commits on the featurebranch and merge it locally. Then once the feature is complete we have a nice history of all work for it on one branch and it can easily be merged into the master branch.

There is of course no reason/difference to do it on GitHub instead of locally and then pushing. It's just a nice GUI feature they provide..

Comment: Wouldn't the first person create this branch locally, then push it for teamwork?   I'm not clear on how this drives the use case of  *instead* of locally?

Comment: Usually that's true, I'd do it like that as well. But the online branch creation is just a neat GUI feature they offer. It can be handy when you're not working on a machine with a local clone of the repo, but you're making some arrangements on how to work...

Comment: @RobbyD Thanks, any comment on my btw question?

Comment: Hey, I cant tell for sure as I dont really use GitHub (using bitbucket), but I would expect so. In any case, just try then checkout the branch and inspect using git log :)